# Is it possible to pass parameter as namespace in Symfony console?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I'd like to pass parameter to Symfony Console thus `commandName:parameter1 parameter2`. Is it possible and how I can do it?

Comment: Actually it's called a parameter not a commande name i don't see why you want to have it in the commande name you can make it required but used like that is weird

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why keeping the : is so important?  As far as Symfony is concerned, commandName:parameter1 is just a string.  The colon means nothing.  Just a convention for readability.  You could, for example, do commandName-parameter1 and Symfony would not care.  I suppose you could check the code to see where the command string ends up being tied to a command and do a bit of processing.  But again, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the addArgument method. you should call it in constructor. There is [a full example in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html) that explains how to use it.

But, the format will be `commandName parameter1 parameter2` or `app:commandName parameter1 parameter2`.

Comment: Thank you but I mean that param will be after the colon. I read documentation and don't found solution for do it.

Comment: Sorry @PavlishinNikita, but I think you cannot do it. (the only way is to edit the bin/console file!)